# How to handle form inputs and validations in React-redux?

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was working on a project which involves heavy usage of forms. I am mainly going to use react, react-router, redux and react-router-redux.

Since there are going to lot of forms with different fields,I was looking for a library which can help me with validations and submissions.

I tried searching bit and came across following libraries:-

1. [formsy-react](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react)- this uses mainly mixins but from what I read mixins are deprecated acc to [this](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.db7jcllbb) post and they dont really work well with ES6.
2. [react-bootstrap-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-validation) - this seems to be broken with the new version of react-bootstrap.

Is there any library which can help me regarding

1. Validation of inputs
2. Submit information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
[Redux-from](http://redux-form.com/6.0.2/)
Its reallly cool with good documentation. Please check.

Comment: Yes just trying that out, I think that should work. Thanks a lot

Comment: Has anyone tried https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form? It has a comparision page at https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/guides/compare-redux-form.html which makes it look terser - but  I'd love to know if anyone has experience of both?